# Why is my question about interrogation being received poorly?

Tags: discussion

I had asked [this question about police being pushy for a false answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/77306/8913), and it has not been received well.  However I'm at a layman's level when it comes to law, and I won't have the opportunity to study very many cases thoroughly, due to working full-time, etc.

I searched this website for a similar question, but didn't find one.  Also the question is based on my understanding of the law at the time.  (For example, you can't lie to police when being questioned, but people in general are not allowed to try to persuade others to commit crimes - although police may have some special allowance here, for undercover work and such.)  I also cited the right to remain silent as being a potential answer to this question, but I just wasn't sure whether that was the case.  I took the question seriously and tried to do a reasonable job with it.

Why was this question downvoted multiple times and received poorly?  Is it because it was perceived as being too basic somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, no question is too basic as no-one knows everything about everything, and although technically correct, two downvotes isn't really "multiple times" when taken in context with some other questions on here.

What got me, was the opening paragraph came across as quite negative with anti-police undertones.  I've no idea if it was intentional or not but that's how I read it.

And, although I'm not an *American* police officer, I do not recognise the systematic coercion alleged in the question - but it may be a just [a language thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74737/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-two-nations-divided-by-a-common-language)